# 3-edge colorings for special cubic graphs on a double torus

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

In [*Complexity of 3-edge-coloring in the class of cubic graphs with a polyhedral embedding in an orientable surface*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X10002386) it is proven that the task to find these colorings is NP-complete in the general case, except for planar graphs.

Is there any particular progress for  bipartite cubic graphs made up of hexagons and octagons on a double torus?

Do efficient solutions exist in that particular case?

Comment: I think I found what I need as comment in [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300396000215?via%3Dihub), saying "Every bipartite graph has chromatic index $\Delta$"...

Comment: There may exist odd cycles non-contractable on the surface.

Comment: @Bullet51 but my graph is bipartite...?

Comment: A bipartite graph has chromatic index=maximum degree. For algorithms, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring#Optimally_coloring_special_classes_of_graphs).